# Cannot print string in C++

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to learn to code in C++ and I come from a C background. 
I wrote a small method to add two binary numbers, while the program runs fine and I'm able to see the right result, I cannot print the "sum" as a string. 
While I can print the "sum" as an array. 
Can someone please help out to tell me what is it that I'm missing?

Here is the code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
using std::string;

class addBinaryClass
{
 private:
   string sum;
 public:
    addBinaryClass()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<255;i++)
          sum[i] = '0';
    }
    string addBinary(string a, string b)
    {
      int l1 = a.length();
      int l2 = b.length();
      int i=0,j=0,k=0,carry=0;
      int num1,num2;
      i = l1-1;
      j= l2-1;
      while ( (i>=0) || (j>=0))
      {
        if(l1>0)
            num1 = (a[i] -'0');
        else
            num1=0;
        if(l2>0)
            num2 = (b[j] - '0');
        else
            num2=0;
        sum[k] = num1 + num2 + carry  ;
        carry =  sum[k] / 2;
        sum[k] = (sum[k] % 2) + '0';
        l1--;l2--;i--;j--,k++;
    }
    sum[k] = (sum [k] + carry);
    reverse(sum.begin(), sum.end());
    cout << "result is " << sum << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<=7;i++)
            cout << sum[i];
    cout << endl;
    return sum;
   }
   void printBinary()
   {
    int l=sum.length();
    cout << "Binary sum "<< endl;
    cout << "length " << l << sum << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "addBinaryEnd" << endl;

  }
  void setString()
  {
     sum = "";
   }
};

int main()
{
 addBinaryClass s;
 s.setString();
 string name = "Add Binary begin";
 cout << name << endl;
 string result =    s.addBinary("10001","10111");
 s.printBinary();
 return 0;
}
```

This is the output that I get. Please note the blank right after "length 0"

```
Add Binary begin
sum is 
00010100
Binary sum 
length 0

addBinaryEnd
```

What I do not understand is why the length of the string is 0. The sum in this case seems to be null. Do I need append null character at the end?

Comment: you never changed the size of your string. all your `sum[i] = ...` assignments aren't doing what you think they are doing :)

Comment: You realize you are assigning ints to the string and not char right?
Also, have you considered using the string's fill contructor instead of that loop? string (size_t n, char c);

Comment: Take a look at [std::stringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)

Comment: When I see lines like `l1--;l2--;i--;j--,k++;` I immediately get *very* concerned. Is this code supposed to be this obfuscated? C++ is a tricky thing to get right in the first place, so don't make your life more difficult by having heaps of variables with meaningless names.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz Shouldnt this take care of converting back to char                                          sum[k] = (sum[k] % 2) + '0';          ?

Comment: A note: `using namespace std;` pulls the entire `std` namespace into the global namespace. This makes `using std::string;` pointless.

Comment: With `sum[i]` you are accessing element i of the string, but nowhere in the code you have increased the size of that string (it's still empty).

Comment: @peedus No. The = operator does not convert int to char. It doesn't give you a compile error because, just like in C, char is an integral type. However, '9' is != 0x9, instead '9' == 0x39. If you want conversion, use a stringstream like Kevin suggested.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherPisz.. I will review this further

Comment: Strings start out with length 0 by default. You need to increase the size first, or else something like `sum[i]` will be accessing non-existent characters in the string.